# How to make this query with ORM::factory

Tags: orm, kohana, max, kohana-3.2

I dont know how to use this "MAX" with ORM. 
Use Kohana 3.2.

```
SELECT MAX( version_id ) AS latest FROM pages_versions WHERE page_id = 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ORM::factory('pages_version')
    ->select(array(DB::expr('MAX(version_id)'), 'max_version'))
    ->where('page_id', '=', '3')
    ->find_all()
```